# Real-time subprocess.popen output (tried everything that i could find)

Tags: python

I tried every thread on this forum. I can not understand why p.stdout is not giving me any output.

```
for x in range(0, int(y)):  
      p = subprocess.Popen(code, shell=True,stdout=PIPE, bufsize=1, universal_newlines=True)  
      p.wait() 
      while True:     
      line = p.stdout.readline() 
      if not line: break 
      if error in line:                     
           p.kill()
```

Comment: How do you know it's not "giving you any output"? You never `print(line)` or anything like that. Also, [`Popen.wait` waits for the process to terminate](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.wait), so this code is doing the exact opposite of reading _real-time_ output.

Comment: What command shell are you trying to make?? I mean what value has "code"

Comment: Adding a specific value for `code` is part of building a [mre] -- code other people can test (without making changes first) to know if an answer successfully resolves the problem. If nobody but you can run it, nobody but you can be certain that an answer completely resolves all issues (though trying to `wait()` before your stdout is closed by the writer is a certain deadlock, so that *particular* issue is plain on its face).

Comment: Charles, you can add any code u wish, i add a process that requires certain files.

Popen.wait - waits for the first subprocess.popen to finish. It produces output. If p.openwait is not there, all iterations are started simultaneously. And i know output is not there because i tested it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well there are a number of things that aren't mentioned in your code but here is what you might need. Instead of using `p.stdout.readline()` use `communicate()`. `P.wait` might also not be very helpful for this code.

```
for x in range(0, int(y)):  
      p = subprocess.Popen(code, shell=True,stdout=PIPE, bufsize=1, universal_newlines=True)    
      output, err = p.communicate()
      if not output:
           break 
      if error in line:                     
           p.kill()
```

If you are expecting whatever you are passing in the shell to fail, I would recommend you put it in an async function using [asyncio](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio.html) and put a timer on it, that way you will have a way to kill the subprocess and it wouldn't completely lock down your code. However, that would take away the synchronous functionality that you are aiming at from the code you pasted here

Comment: Thanks. Why do u mean P.wait is not helpful? If i do not do p.wait i will end up with every iteration running at the same time which for my case causes havoc.

Comment: You will not, it is subprocess not multiprocess, meaning the code will run synchronously, which means that the subprocess will have to get completed first before the next line of your code runs, so the `wait` might not really be a good fit here, but if you really think it must be there then go for it